# Windows Phone - Storyboard TargetName in runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, storyboard

How can I set TargetName for DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames  in runtime?

```
<Storyboard x:Name="sr">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="keyFrameDA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)"  Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

I have tried

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(keyFrameDA, "cardBack");
```

But there is not such property for DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames. Thanks.

**Update**:
And this error is throwing when I am using this code:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(keyFrameDa, new PropertyPath(PlaneProjection.RotationXProperty));
Storyboard.SetTarget(keyFrameDa, cardBack.Projection);
```

Error: KeyFramesProperty -  Cannot fetch the value of field 'KeyFramesProperty' because information about the containing class is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, how about this...

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(keyFrameDa, new PropertyPath(PlaneProjection.RotationXProperty));
Storyboard.SetTarget(keyFrameDa, cardBack.Projection);
```

Comment: Edited... Sorry, not at a machine I can do a trial compile.

Comment: Thanks. In my opinion it must work. But it is giving "Value can not be null.
Parameter name: element" error in first row.

Comment: May I upload  the solution to the SkyDrive for you? If you have time? )) Because it is a little bit urgent.

Comment: And the exact error is: KeyFramesProperty = Cannot fetch the value of field 'KeyFramesProperty' because information about the containing class is unavailable.

Comment: I'm not at a computer where I can compile and assist, unfortunately. Maybe someone else can hop in and help further.