# Make a button flash in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, button

Hi in my application I would like my buttons to flash for a short moment as to prompt which button to press in which order. Anyone know how to do this, I was thinking maybe hiding the button and then pausing for a short period and then enabling it again, but not sure that's such a great idea.

```
private void display_combination()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_INPUT; i++)
        {
            switch(combination[i])
            {
                case 0: button_flash(this.Up_Button); break;
                case 1: button_flash(this.Down_Button); break;
                case 2: button_flash(this.Left_Button); break;
                case 3: button_flash(this.Right_Button); break;                    
            }
        }
    }

void button_flash(Button b)
    {
        b.IsEnabled.Equals(0);
        //perhaps a pause her and then enable the button again?

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way here would be using a storyboard with switching targets on completion. Here are some resources to get you started on that:

- [Intro to Storyboard animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Here is how to set the Storyboard target at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694136/windows-phone-storyboard-targetname-in-runtime)