# Is it possible to change a storyboard's target in the code in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, storyboard, windows-store-apps

I have a single storyboard that I would like to apply to the clicked Windows.Shapes.Rectangle. Is this possible? Would binding work?

```
<Storyboard x:Name="TileClick">
    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName= "{Binding}" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Please check an answer or add more help to us

Answer (score 3):

Before you configure another target for the animation, you have to stop the actual animation.
Like That:

```
 ColorAnimation.Stop();
 Storyboard.SetTarget(ColorAnimation, myRectangle);
 ColorAnimation.Begin();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give a name to ColorAnimation like that:

```
<ColorAnimation x:Name="Ca" Duration="0:0:1" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName= "{Binding}" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
```

And then, you can access to target data in C# like

```
Ca.TargetName = YOURTARGET;
```

or

```
Ca.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, YOURTARGET.Name);
```

Also I find an another answer on stackoverflow: [Windows Phone - Storyboard TargetName in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694136/windows-phone-storyboard-targetname-in-runtime)

And an another additional code if others doesn't work

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, myRectangle);
```

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/03/24/create-an-animation-in-code.aspx

Comment: I did that, there is no TargetName property

Comment: Sorry you're right. Can you try Ca.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, YOUROBJECT.Name);

I changed something on my post, please have a look again.

Comment: I get this error: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Operation is not valid on an active Animation or Storyboard.  Root Storyboard must be stopped first.